# How to float an icon right for high resolution but add it after the text on a low resolution?

Tags: css

For different resolutions my site needs to look differently, with the same html.
On the high resolution I would like a text first and an icon floating to the right of the parent container. For the low resolution the icon should be directly after the text.

```
Large resolution text here                                              floating icon
Might be several lines

----

small resolution Text - Icon directly following
```

I can only get the floating icon to be on the correct line if I place this first in the html otherwise it moves to the second line.

I've tried variations of clear, floats, absolute and relative positioning, vertical align, and css columns but it either works correctly for large resolutions or small ones, but not both.

This example works for the large resolutions:

```css
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .right-icon {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-icon">Icon</div>
  <div class="text-left">Text</div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout combined with [mediaquery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-icon">Icon</div>
  <div class="text-left">Text</div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I'm actually using these, I probably simplified the example too much. I'll update my question

Comment: I see.So combination of flexbos + media query then, lemmeesee

Comment: Probably another way is to use <span> tags instead of <div> tags

Comment: Details may make it easy to help solve problem.